# React-router app deployed on different locations (subdirectories)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a react-router app that I have to deploy on different locations (subdirectories), so the basename would change. For example it should have the following paths:

`/` (production)
`/appname/env1`
`/appname/env2`

I want to use Browser History, so I implemented the `BrowserRouter` from react-router, but I cannot pass to it a static basename. And obviously the routing won't work, for example if I don't pass any basename to `BrowserRouter`, if my homepage route is:

`<Route path="/" exact component={MyComponent} />`

it won't work when accessing to `/appname/env1` or `/appname/env2`.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for with react-router?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a base name like below

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { useBasename } from 'history'
<Router history={useBasename(() => browserHistory)({ basename: BASENAME })}>
```

and you can set the basename maybe in your webpack configuration

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BASENAME: JSON.stringify("/appname/env1/")
    }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if I don't know the basename in advance? In my case, we are deploying on a different subfolder of an environment for each development branch, for testing purposes.

Comment: i don't know if the following would help you but how about creating a variable and use it instead of BASENAME when you know what is the environment

Comment: If you're using create-react-app you could also define environment variables. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<Router basename={window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/[^/]*)$/, "")}>
```

this has no trailing slash as required in docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

example

```
var pathname = "/pathname/routeName" 
console.log(pathname.replace(/(\/[^/]*)$/, "") //returns "/pathname"
```

see: https://regexr.com/5v3s3