# React Router with relative path deployment

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My question is concerning the `react-router-dom` in conjunction with deployment to a relative path (see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths). On my dev environment the router is working fine, but once i build and deploy my application with the `homepage` tag set in `package.json` the router does not seem to work anymore.

First of all i would assume that it would be working. After all it's a build option by react to make a build for a specific url and i would assume the same functionality with that relative path in place. However neither the `<Link to="">` parts nor the `<Switch>` do respect the relative path of my react app.

Second of all i have not found a solution to circumvent this behavior. Any ideas?

Other question dealing with react router and relative paths are focusing on a totally different topic. So i have not found an answer to my question. This [React-router app deployed on different locations (subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250223/react-router-app-deployed-on-different-locations-subdirectories) is maybe getting close and could be a way to deal with that.

For info:

```
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
```

**EDIT and PS:**

I would probably just need to set a basename. If the basename is changing i would at least want to infer it from the setting in the `package.json` and not change my code depending on some `package.json` setting.

**EDIT 2:**

*I could use `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to set the basename to the correct URL. However the routes are still not matching. The links however appear to be fine, so `<Link to="/xx">` would actually result in an link to `{process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/xx` which is the desired behavior, but the routers `<Switch>` does not match them.* **Actually this is the answer and you can scratch that.**

Using `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` does solve my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To anyone stumbling across the same problem: Read the edits in my original question. Using `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` does solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me, basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} **doesn't work**. But

```
<Router basename={window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/[^/]+)$/, "")}>
```

does the magic, without trailing slash as required in docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

example

```
var pathname = "/pathname/routeName" 
console.log(pathname.replace(/(\/[^/]+)$/, "") //returns /pathname
```