# React-Router dose not work while using BrowserRouter after Build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So i have a app which is using React-Router BrowserRouter to navigate between different components

Code:

```
return (
    <Router>
        <div className="container">
            <Navbar logged={loggedIn} />

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Welcome />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/logout" exact>
                    <Logout loggedSet={setLoggedIn} logged={loggedIn} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login" exact>
                    <Login onLogin={login} loggedIn={loggedIn} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
                    {loggedIn ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
                </Route>
                <Route path="/add" exact>
                    {loggedIn ? <Add /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
                    <Add />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

When i build this this shows a Blank Page i got to know to add "homepage": ".", in package.json . I did so and not it shows Navbar Component but it dosent show any components which are under  I searched and found we need to use HashRouter. is using hashrouter correct if so how to change my code to use hashrouter.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the generic route last, without the `exact` as shown below. Otherwise it'll only show up if your are exactly at root `/`, any hashes, query params etc will cause it to not match and your app will not show anything:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/logout" exact>
        <Logout loggedSet={setLoggedIn} logged={loggedIn} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" exact>
        <Login onLogin={login} loggedIn={loggedIn} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
        {loggedIn ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
    </Route>
    <Route path="/add" exact>
        {loggedIn ? <Add /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        <Add />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
        <Welcome />
     </Route>
 </Switch>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be the other way around? If you put `exact` for just `/` the route wont to this if any text is added after, so you dont need to put all the exact for the rest

Comment: OP said *"this shows a Blank Page"* - in the case of a switch with only exact matches it'll show blank page when there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

you are putting the build in a subfolder?. If yes check this:
[React Router with relative path deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572259/react-router-with-relative-path-deployment/67064651#67064651)

and this
[React-router app deployed on different locations (subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250223/react-router-app-deployed-on-different-locations-subdirectories/67064718#67064718)