# React-router app deployed on dynamic subdirectories. manual navigation doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kubernetes, nginx, vite

I'm using React-Router-Dom and Vite on my project.
The app will be deployed onto a dynamic subdirectory that is not known pre-deployment.

Thus, using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250223/react-router-app-deployed-on-different-locations-subdirectories): I set the base name of the router to match whatever the value of the `/generatedsubdirectory`.

The in-app routing is triggered by the user via UI buttons in the app.

Per example:

- Current `example.com/generatedsubdirectory/view`  → Button click → URL changes to `example.com/generatedsubdirectory/secondview` and `<MobileElement />` is displayed. The same applies from `/secondview` → `/view`.

### The Problem:

In App navigation as shown in the above example **works**, **BUT** When the user manually navigates to `/secondview` by tying the `/secondview` in the browser URL field, the router doesn't return anything!

Basically any route that involve: `<Navigate to={Constants.AppRoutes.ROUTE_XYZ} />` doesn't support manual navigation!.

### The code:

Here is the code:

.env

```
VITE_BASE_PATH = /
```

router.tsx:

```
export const AppRoutes = () => [
    { path: Constants.AppRoutes.ROOT_PATH, element: <Navigate to={Constants.AppRoutes.ROUTE_A} /> },
    {
        path: Constants.AppRoutes.Route_A,
        element: <AppLayout />,
    },
    {
        path: Constants.AppRoutes.ROUTE_B,
        element: <MobileElement />,
    },
    {
        // -> *
        path: Constants.AppRoutes.WILD_CARD_PATH,
        element: <h1>This route: {window.location.pathname} does not exists.</h1>,
    },
];
```

Constants.ts:

```js
AppRoutes: {
    ROOT_PATH: '/',
    ROUTE_A: '/view',
    ROUTE_B: '/secondview',
    RELATIVE_PATH: window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/[^/]*)$/, ''),
    WILD_CARD_PATH: '*',
}
```

App.ts

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
    const appRoutes = AppRoutes();
    const appRouter = createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
            <>
                {appRoutes.map((route) => (
                    <Route index key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
                ))}
            </>,
        ),
        {
            basename: Constants.AppRoutes.RELATIVE_PATH,
            future: {
                v7_normalizeFormMethod: true,
                v7_relativeSplatPath: true,
            },
        },
    );
    return <RouterProvider router={appRouter} />;
}
```

I have read the documentation of the React-Router but haven't found a solution yet.

### EDIT1:

Nginx.conf

```
server {
  server_tokens off;

  listen 8080;

  absolute_redirect off;

  rewrite ^/ac-ui/(.*)$ /$1 last;
  location "/" {
    autoindex off;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location = /404.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main if=$loggable;
}
```

Comment: *Where* are you deploying your app? What server or hosting service are you using? To be clear, this ***is not*** a frontend issue that can be solved using React-Router, it's a backend server configuration issue where the server/hosting service needs to be configured to return the root index.html file for ***all*** page requests into the app. It's only after the app is correctly served to a client that the client-side routing becomes relevant. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a section relevant to your use case.

Comment: I'm using vite to serve it. And I'm just placing it under a sub dir in my example.com/subdir/. For deployment, I'm using normal nginx that is forwarding the index.html of the vite server.

Comment: I see, so you are still just serving it on `localhost` then? AFAIK this still just serves the app from `"/"`, so if you are using a `basename` prop on the router you'll need to manually navigate to *that* directory after the app is running and then I believe routing/navigation should work as expected.

Comment: I edited the post to contain my nginx.conf. I'm deploying it on a local server running nginx in Kubernetes cluster. The app is accessible with a custom domain and upon deployment it will assign it a generated DIR under which the app will be deployed.